# SQL find related products based on filters

Tags: sql

For this example lets say there are three tables in my database.

**products**

- name
- id

**filters**

- id
- name

**product_filters**

- id
- product_id
- filter_id

I want to suggest a product to a visitor based on the filter of the current product they are viewing.

The product_filters table might contain the following data

```
 id    |   product_id    |   filter_id
 ======================================
 1     |    1            |    1
 2     |    1            |    2
 3     |    1            |    3
 4     |    2            |    1
 5     |    3            |    1
 6     |    3            |    2
 7     |    5            |    1
 8     |    5            |    8
 9     |    5            |    7
```

In this situation when the user opens product 1 the following stats 'happen'

```
product          equals       filters
------------------------------------------
product 2        1  (1)         1 
product 3        2  (1,2)       2
product 4        0              0
product 5        1  (1)         3
```

To give the user the best relevant result I want to return the x amount of products that match the most in the following order:

1. most equal
2. most equal lowest amount of filters
3. closest product - id

The order in the above case would be.

```
3,2,5,4
```

I always need an x amount of results.

What I currently have.

**Count number of filters, limit to x result.**

```
SELECT product_id, count(product_id) 
FROM product_filters 
GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 5;
```

**Count amount of equal filters**

```
SELECT product_id, count(product_id) 
FROM product_filters  
WHERE filter_id = 1 
OR filter_id = 2 
OR filter_id = 3  
GROUP BY product_id;
```

How could I combine these querys in a way that I always get x result (even if there are no matches)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you're getting the results listed in the stats table by opening product 1. Can you use more defined variable values, something like

Comment: id prod id filter id 
1   a              n 
2   b              o 
3   c              p.  4   d              q 
5   e              r 
6   f              s 
7   g              t 
8   h              u 
9   i              v

Comment: Can't get the columns eo line up properly

Comment: @LynneDavidson i've added the equal value to the chart (same filter_id as product 1 has).

Comment: Hi, which result you wanna see if there are no Matches? See you query from above? All items?!

Comment: @thezapper dosnt matter much maybey closest id. I always want x amount of results, even with 0 matches